# wagtail page model reference in HTML template

Tags: wagtail

According to [Wagtail source code](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/wagtail/core/models/__init__.py),

```
class Page(AbstractPage, index.Indexed, ClusterableModel, metaclass=PageBase):
  def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            PAGE_TEMPLATE_VAR: self,
            'self': self,
            'request': request,
        }

        if self.context_object_name:
            context[self.context_object_name] = self

        return context
```

By default, any subclass from wagtail `Page` model, can use `self` & `request` in its HTML template.

**However, in [official doc](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html?highlight=wagtailcore_tag#wagtail-template-tags), why we can use `page.body` instead of `self.body` after `{% load wagtailcore_tags %}`? I did not see this reflected in any source code.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `page` and `self` are indeed valid when using the standard Django template engine. However, `self` is a reserved word in [the Jinja2 template engine](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/jinja2.html), so the documentation encourages `page` for consistency (and to make it easier for developers to switch to Jinja2 in future if they choose to).

For the record, here's the PR where the alternative variable name was introduced: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/1571